# Perfomance Restkit com AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, restful, slim

Montei um restserver utilizando o Slim Framework (PHP), conectando em um BD MySQL. Está em um servidor dedicado e com performance moderada, ou seja a resposta está bem rápida.

Porém fiz um app de teste no IOS onde eu consulto essa api e monto um table view com o resultado. No wifi vai rápido, porém no "3g" ele demora de 15 a 30 segundos para carregar!

Estou utilizando o Restkit com AFNetworking.
O link da api é: http://api.guia-se.com.br/rafael/ (Podem acessar p/ ver o resultado/velocidade)
É normal demorar todo esse tempo para montar o UITableView em um json pequeno destes?

Alguém sabe como poderia resolver isso?

Answer (score 1):

Tudo indica que é um problema de network mas mesmo para uma conexão 3G, é muito tempo para obter dados.

Fiz um benchmark bem simples, o tempo minimo para o seu serviço responder foi de 511ms e o maior 2.11secs, ou seja, ta tudo dentro do normal.

Talvez seja um problema da sua rede de dados, que não tem nada a ver com AFNetworking ou ResKit.

**UPDATE**
A hipostese levantada sobre a tabela está sendo atualizada fora da main thread faz sentido.

Antes de mais nada, para ter certeza, coloque um breakpoint no ponto onde sua tabela atualiza e execute em modo debug, quando a aplicação parar no breakpoint, verifique se o stack está dentro da main thread, veja no exemplo abaixo como deve aparecer.

[image: Exemplo main thread]

Se não estiver parado na main thread, use a solução abaixo para executar a chamada que faz sua tabela atualizar.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  // execute aqui a chamada que faz sua tabela atualizar
});
```

Comment: Eu cheguei a testar outros aplicativos e funcionam normalmente. Claro que a rede é lenta (brasil né) mas esse aplicativo em específico está com esse problema. Em um grupo me falaram que uma possibilidade é eu estar atualizando a TableView fora da main thread. Como sou iniciante, não entendi muito bem. Acha que poderia ser isso?

Comment: É bem provavel que sim, para você ter certeza, coloca um breakpoint no lugar onde sua table view é atualizada. Se o stack não estiver na main thread, você pode colocar a chamada que faz sua tabela atualizar dentro de um bloco que muda ela para a main thread, vou atualizar minha resposta com um exemplo.